# Change folder attribute to hidden on iOS (FMX, C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want to create a directory at runtime and make it hidden.  Using [this example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FileAttributes_(C%2B%2B)) i tried the following code and it works fine on Win32 but errors on iOS build:

```
UnicodeString TestPath;
TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath() + "\\test\\";
TDirectory::CreateDirectory(TestPath);
TFileAttributes dirattribs;
dirattribs = TDirectory::GetAttributes(TestPath);
dirattribs = dirattribs << TFileAttribute::faHidden;
TDirectory::SetAttributes(TestPath, dirattribs);
```

The build error i get when building for iOS or Android is `no member named 'faHidden' in 'System::Ioutils::TFileAttribute'`.  So, how can i change folder attributes on iOS and Android?

p.s.  Using Rad Studio 10.3.2 (C++ Builder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`faHidden` is not implement on Posix systems. This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFileAttribute) in Embarcadero's DocWiki.  `faHidden` is only available on Windows.

To create a folder that is hidden from the user on Posix systems, you can simply prepend the folder name with a leading dot:

```cpp
UnicodeString TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath();
#ifdef _Windows
TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(TestPath, _D("test"));
TDirectory::CreateDirectory(TestPath);
TFileAttributes dirattribs = TDirectory::GetAttributes(TestPath);
dirattribs = dirattribs << TFileAttribute::faHidden;
TDirectory::SetAttributes(TestPath, dirattribs);
#else
TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(TestPath, _D(".test"));
TDirectory::CreateDirectory(TestPath);
#endif
```

Note, it is possible to create a folder with a leading dot on Windows, too. It just won't have an effect on the folder's hidden attribute, you would still have to set that explicitly:

```cpp
UnicodeString TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath();
TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(TestPath, _D(".test"));
TDirectory::CreateDirectory(TestPath);
#ifdef _Windows
TFileAttributes dirattribs = TDirectory::GetAttributes(TestPath);
dirattribs = dirattribs << TFileAttribute::faHidden;
TDirectory::SetAttributes(TestPath, dirattribs);
#endif
```

Comment: Remy - i had to tweek the 1st line under the `#ifdef _Windows` to this: `TestPath = TestPath + "\\test";`

Comment: @relayman357 Don't do it that way. Do use `TPath::Combine()`. I just forgot to save the return value. I updated my answer.